# How can I create two SSH keys with the same algorithm?

Tags: ssh, key

I am trying to create two SSH keys with the same algorithm:
ssh-keygen -t rsa -b 4096

The first one I can create correctly, but when I want to create the second key I get an error that informs me that a key with this name already exists.

If I create it with another algorithm, example dsa works correctly for me, but I would like the two keys to be with the same algorithm.

Is there a solution for this or should I use the same algorithm?

I am using Ubuntu 20.04

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the -f flag to specify the file name. `ssh-keygen -f <filename> -t rsa -b 4096`

Comment: This solution worked for me. I am very grateful.